# C# Process exited event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am creating a process which is responsible for running a certain program, I have added an event when the program is terminated, however when I close the program the event does not start.

Here is my code, previous create process my program unzip .exe file and run.

Create new process with event:

```
Process installerProcess = new Process();
installerProcess.StartInfo.FileName = unpackPath + @"\" + unpackFileName;
installerProcess.Exited += InstallerProcess_Exited;
installerProcess.Start();
```

Event:

```
private void InstallerProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Process end");
}
```

Comment: You might have to add the `-o` option to overwrite existing files without prompting, otherwise unzip might be waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `EnableRaisingEvents` to true on the `Process` object:

```
Process installerProcess = new Process();
installerProcess.StartInfo.FileName = unpackPath + @"\" + unpackFileName;
installerProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
installerProcess.Exited += InstallerProcess_Exited;
installerProcess.Start();
```